# How to swap column 1 column 2 values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to swap column 1 column 2 values based on condition if column 1 value is less than column 2 then I want to swap

Input

```
Index column 1 column 2
0       5         6
1       4         3
2       6         8
3       2         4
```

Output

```
Index   column 1  column 2
0         6          5
1         4          3
2         8          6
3         4          2
```

Comment: efficient and concise method: `df.where(df['column 1']<df['column 2'], df.values[::-1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) here. Create a boolean mask where `col1` < `col2`.

```
m = df["col1"].lt(df["col2"])
df.assign(
    col1=df["col1"].mask(m, df["col2"]), col2=df["col2"].mask(m, df["col1"])
)


   Index  col1  col2
0      0     6     5
1      1     4     3
2      2     8     6
3      3     4     2
```